# Is there a run-time overhead to using string interpolation to insert a constant?

Tags: c#, performance, string-interpolation

I have a class which has 3 methods, each method starts a new `System.Diagnostics.Process` where some unique arguments are passed in along with some standard ones shared by all 3.

In order to reduce duplication I currently have all the consistent arguments stored as a class-level constant and then interpolate them in as the method runs.

```
private const string File = "file.exe";
private const string StandardAgs = "--whatever";

public void DoA()
{
    string command = $"{File} unique args for A {StandardAgs}";
    Process.Start(command);
}

public void DoB()
{
    string command = $"{File} unique args for B {StandardAgs}";
    Process.Start(command);
}

public void DoC()
{
    string command = $"{File} unique args for C {StandardAgs}";
    Process.Start(command);
}
```

Is there a run-time processing overhead to this interpolation? Or, because all the class-level variables are constants, will the compiler recognise that they can be interpolated at compile-time?

Failing that, would I need to have all my strings be constant to achieve zero run-time interpolation, like so?

```
private const string File = "file.exe";
private const string StandardAgs = "--whatever";

private const string Acommand = $"{File} unique args for A {StandardAgs}";
private const string Bcommand = $"{File} unique args for B {StandardAgs}";
private const string Ccommand = $"{File} unique args for C {StandardAgs}";

public void DoA()
{
    Process.Start(Acommand);
}

public void DoB()
{
    Process.Start(Bcommand);
}

public void DoC()
{
    Process.Start(Ccommand);
}
```

I recognise that only second example stores the strings statically in memory rather than on a per-instance basis but I'm not concerned about the memory footprint, only how much string interpolation occurs at run-time.

Comment: Interpolation becomes a string.Format call. You would need to use concatenation in your last example to get constant strings, because even with only constants, `string.Format` is not a constant expression. Are you trying to get these strings at a very, very high frequency? I doubt there's much measurable run-time impact.

Comment: @JonathonChase Thank you for your response. There's the potential my program will make lots of recursive calls here so I wanted to look into this before I designed it one way or the other. I think I reality I'll be fine with the interpolation overhead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a short program and then run it through ILSpy.

c#:

```
const string Foo = "Hello";

static void Main()
{
    var bar = $"{Foo}Bar!";
    Console.WriteLine(bar);
}
```

IL:

```
IL_0001: ldstr "{0}Bar!"
IL_0006: ldstr "Hello"
IL_000b: call string [mscorlib]System.String::Format(string, object)
IL_0010: stloc.0
IL_0011: ldloc.0
IL_0012: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
```

Looks like it turns into a string.Format call and gets computed at runtime.

So yes, there is a (very very small) performance impact.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll have to look into ILSpy :)